# Menus without background and user pref have parts missing

Tags: interface, linux, installation

In blender version 2.69 and 2.70 and 2.70a the menus have no background and I can't find out why.

This is most likely system-problem; not a direct Blender3D issue because this error happened when I updated to Linux Mint 16.

I assume that some library (python?) version causes this error.

I have been searching for two days without any hint regarding this error so a little help/hint is appreciated.

Image examples:

[image: Menus with no background]

[image: User pref with missing parts]

Comment: In my oppinion this is a bug. You should file a bug report to the [Blender Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/).

Comment: Have you tried to reset to Factory Setting?

Comment: Resetting to factory setting has also been tried but no effect.
I think I will follow maddin45's advice and make at bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was not a Blender3D issue.

It was an conflict between Linux Mint window-manager libraries.

Perhaps KDE vs Gnome or different versions of Gnome.

I removed some Gnome libraries and the menues in Blender worked again.

Thanks for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Check your blender user preferences. Under the Themes tab in the user preferences go to the `User Interface` settings. Then scroll down to the item that says *Menu Back:*, check if the *Inner:* color has any alpha. If that is at 0 then that is your problem.

Also If you scroll all the way down on that same page you will come to a item called *Menu shadow:* Check if that is above 0, and that the size is above 0px.

If these two did not help then it is a bug with your system.
[image: Blender User Prefences]

Comment: The "Menu Back" did not have any alpha and I changed both the alpha and the colour but this did not alleviate the problem.
I also tried to change other menu "inner" colour settings but nothing seemed to change.
"Menu shadow" did have a strength of 0.5 and a width of 12px.